# 5V Step Up Converter Drops Voltage to 2.3 Volts when Connected to Device

Tags: batteries, wiring, step-up

Recently I combined two 18650 batteries in Parallel, and attached the output of the Paralleled 18650 batteries to a 5V Step UP Converter.

**Device draws 5V 4a**.

**Here is a picture to the step up**:
[image]

While the Paralleled batteries are the input, when I set the output on the adjustable converter to 5V and connect my battery powered device, **the output Voltage drops to 2.3V and 1.3A**.

I am not sure why this is happening: immediately when I connect the battery powered device to the output with AWG Gauge wires, the Voltage I set is seemingly overriden.

Thanks!

Here is the data sheet:
[image]

Comment: What does the datasheet of that device say it needs for input? How much can the input provide and how much does it drop?

Comment: @PlasmaHH The data sheet states a 96% efficiency. I am paralleling two Samsung 30Q batteries. The input says it needs a minimum of 3Vs, that is all. Here is the link: https://www.ebay.com/itm/100W-DC-DC-Boost-Step-up-Adjustable-Converter-3V-35V-to-3-5V-35V-5V-12V-24V-9A/263086934802?hash=item3d41340b12:g:baEAAOSwux5YOmtr

Comment: @PlasmaHH I edited my post to say that my device is drawing 5V 4A

Comment: we are still waiting for the answer to all of my questions.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Sorry, just wanted to get a quick response back at you. Working on it. Here: The product states a minimum input of 3V, with no specification for minimum amperage input. Two Paralleled 18650s can provide, say, 15A constantly. The device rates at a 96% efficiency. Not sure what you mean by drop, but the Voltage of the paralleled battery pack ranges from 4.2V to around 2.5V as I have a BMS protecting against over-discharge.

Comment: "Two Paralleled 18650s can provide, say, 15A constantly" that very much depends on the actual batteries used and their condition. I am specifically asking about those that you are using. What does their datasheet say? "Not sure what you mean by drop" I mean what does the voltage of the batteries drop to while being used. You know that they do that, don't you?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I edited my post with the relevant statistics for the 30Q battery.

Comment: What is the input voltage when the output is dropping?

Comment: 20W is a lot.  Do you have a datasheet for your converter?  How much power can it deliver?

Comment: @evildemonic batteries at at 3.54Volts each

Comment: @evildemonic batteries are at 3.54 Volts Each, Converter is linked here: https://www.ebay.com/itm/100W-DC-DC-Boost-Step-up-Adjustable-Converter-3V-35V-to-3-5V-35V-5V-12V-24V-9A/263086934802?hash=item3d41340b12:g:baEAAOSwux5YOmtr It can allow for a minimum of 3V input at a maximum of 9 A of Output at from 3V-35V.

Comment: Ok, it appears as if your module does is not able to meet its own specifications.  Since you are running at lower voltages than anything in the test data, my best guess would be that this module cannot supply full power with such little input voltage.  Note that you are right at the bare minimum input voltage.

Comment: The page says "Note: When input voltage is less than 4V, onboard voltmeter will not work". How are you measuring all these voltages?

Comment: @Finbarr Using a Multi Meter

Comment: @Finbarr could it be the "ebay"-ness of the product? Is there a way for it to accept lower voltages?

Comment: Unlikely, the limit is probably determined by the chip itself.

Comment: Those cheap Ebay modules rarely live up to their claims, and expecting 20W output with ~3V in is asking a lot (I doubt the inductor is capable of dealing with the required peak currents). Oh, and about this: _"The device rates at a 96% efficiency."_ - **maybe** it can do 96% at some specific combination of input voltage, output voltage, and power (although I'm still sceptical). But it **definitely** won't do it for all combinations, and most likely not for a low input voltage (which happens to be your scenario). All this is partly normal boost limitations, and partly Ebay "marketing".

Comment: @marcelm Where can I go to get what I want?: 5V Boost Minimum Input Voltage as Low as 2.5V handles an input up to 10A? that actually works. Only place I found was ebay! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I can only speculate, as you didn't mention what you measured the input voltage at under load (or at least didn't say whether it was under load or not):

You're operating close to the lower limit of input voltage.  Your batteries might be at 3.54V with no load, but the battery ESR and state of charge (as well as any wiring between it and the board) might cause it to droop when you pull current.  Perhaps there exists an undervoltage mechanism to shut down the supply when the input is too low.  If so, it would kick in and shut down the regulator, which would result in...that's right, lower current drain.  The battery voltage quickly recovers, and at that point the regulator kicks in again.

If this is what's happening, you can measure the voltage **at the input of your board** and see if it's dropping to <3V when your 5V device is connected.

If that's the case, I'd suggest trying a bench supply, but I suspect this is supposed to be your bench supply.  Make sure all your battery wiring is as short and as solid as possible, to eliminate that as a cause.  Failing that, try paralleling more batteries to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Hi Cristobol, I measured the Voltage input at the input of my board, as you suggested, and it measured 3.54V. Same problem exists even with a more expensive board with perfect ratings. However, this time, when I connect the output I am measuring a 3V output versus a 2.3V output in comparison to the Ebay board I bought.

Comment: It looks like now, with the new board, the voltage or the input at the board is now the voltage at the output when connect to load. When it's not connected to any load, the board works perfectly.